# Javascript if else always return to 2 else if

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am running this page that is based on Html + JavaScript.
This is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
/*var test = "Hello";
document.getElementById("mytext").value = test;
*/

function myFunction() {

var resultado;
var c1 = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
var c2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
var c3 = document.getElementById("mySelect3").value;
if(c1 == "nao" , c2 == "nao" , c3 == "nao" ){
    resultado = 1;

}

else if(c1 == "nao" , c2 == "nao" , c3 == "sim" ){
    resultado = 2;

} 

else if

(c1 == "nao" , c2 == "sim" , c3 == "sim" ){

    resultado = 3;
}

else {
    resultado = 4;
}
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultado;

}



</script>
</script>


<form action="fb.php" method="POST">

<select name="test" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="selecione">selecione...</option>
<option value="sim">sim</option>
<option value="nao">nao</option>
<option value="jim">jim</option>

</select>
<select name="test" id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="selecione">selecione...</option>
<option value="sim">sim</option>
<option value="nao">nao</option>

</select>
<select name="test" id="mySelect3" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="selecione">selecione...</option>
<option value="sim">sim</option>
<option value="nao">nao</option>

</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the first condition returns `1`, which is fine.

but , the third condition `(c1 == "nao" , c2 == "sim" , c3 == "sim")` always returns 2.

I have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qoL6e0ca/

Someone could help me, please?

Comment: Thiago you should use `===` instead of `==`. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: thanks matias , i'll learn more about js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anding of `iF` statements is using `&&` like `if(c1 == "nao" && c2 == "nao" && c3 == "sim" )`